# How do I format a read-only field in the Django admin with a 3rd party library?

Tags: django, django-admin

I am using [django-prettyjson](https://github.com/kevinmickey/django-prettyjson) to format my JSONFields in the admin. My code is setup as follows:

**models.py**

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
    structure = JSONField(default=dict, blank=True, null=True)
    static_structure = JSONField(default=dict, blank=True, null=True, editable=False)
```

**admin.py**

```
class MyModelAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    formfield_overrides = {
        JSONField: {'widget': PrettyJSONWidget }
    }

    def get_readonly_fields(self, request, obj=None):
        if obj:
            return ('static_structure')
        else:
            return super(MyModelAdmin, self).get_readonly_fields(request, obj)

admin.site.register(MyModel, MyModelAdmin)
```

In other words, one of the JSONFields is not editable and read-only. It appears on my admin panel, but its not being affected by the widget which renders the other field as formatted JSON.

Any way to fix this? Looking through plain-text JSON data is a complete drag. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

5 years too late.. but better late than never.

Here is a starting point: https://til.simonwillison.net/django/pretty-print-json-admin

Basically, you want to override the `change_form_template` for the admin class and update it. In the linked blog, it changes all forms, which may or may not something you want.

Not the most elegant solution, but I got the [jsoneditor](https://github.com/josdejong/jsoneditor/tree/master) to work with the following (the JS could be optimised a bit more I think). If the field I was after is `mytargetfield` then:

```
{% extends 'admin/change_form.html' %}
{% block admin_change_form_document_ready %}
{{ block.super }}

<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jsoneditor/9.10.2/jsoneditor.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jsoneditor/9.10.2/jsoneditor-minimalist.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function(){

        django.jQuery('div.form-row.field-mytargetfield > div > div').addClass('current-json').parent().hide();
        
        let currentJsonEl = django.jQuery('div.form-row.field-mytargetfield > div > div.current-json');
        let jsonData;

        try {
            jsonData = JSON.parse(currentJsonEl.text());
            // append editor to parent element
            django.jQuery('div.form-row.field-mytargetfield').append('<p>mytargetfield:</p><div id="jsoneditor"></div>');

            const container = document.getElementById('jsoneditor')
            const options = {
                mode: 'view'
            }
            const editor = new JSONEditor(container, options, jsonData)

        } catch {
            // Not valid JSON
            currentJsonEl.show()
        }
    });

</script>
{% endblock %}
```